# Ionic 3 save facebook user to firestore database

Tags: javascript, ionic3, firebase-authentication

Im using facebook login to my app from some tutorials facebook login is done but now i want to save the user data in firestore db . mean when i login user data show in console in json format . i need to save the email , username ,and uid in firestore db . Can any one please tell me how i can do this . ?

```
 facebookLogin(): Promise<any> {
 return this.facebook.login(['email'])
  .then( response => {
    const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider
      .credential(response.authResponse.accessToken);

    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential)
      .then( success => { 
        console.log("Firebase success: " + JSON.stringify(success)); 
      });

  }).catch((error) => { console.log(error) });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this:

```
signWithFacebook() {
let provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect( provider ).then(
  () => {
    firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(
      data => alert(data)
    );
  }
)
```

}

This function will open the native Facebook app, when the user login, Facebook returns the user data... After, you could make this: (using AngularFireDatabase)

```
const user = {...data from Facebook}
this.afDB.list("YourDocumentName").push(user);
```

Comment: its opening in browser . i tried with another method but send user to firestore by this way            
             this.afs.collection("userr").doc("uid").set(userr);                                                          now its working fine but not saving the doc as uid

Comment: Well, your could use: AngularFireDatabase from angularfire2 and do something like this:

constructor(
    private afDB: AngularFireDatabase
  ) { }

this.afDB.database.ref('users').child('userUID').set(userObject);

Comment: And the user will saved in the users' doc and it key will be the uuid